# How to send each row of a DataFrame to a Step Function, get response back, and store it in a column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, pyspark, aws-step-functions

I am in a Glue job script with a DataFrame of 800 rows. I have a StepFunction which can take a row in JSON format, return the response.

From the Glue job, I need to pass each ROW of DataFrame to StepFunction, get the response and save it in a column in the DataFrame.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the apply function? 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

With this function, it is easy to pass your data through a function and then store the results in a column. 
Ex:
`df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda row : function(row.column), axis=1)`

Comment: I think he mentioned about AWS Step Function services.  @Srinin, please clarify or edit your post

Comment: I realized, Step Function can be called from a function in the Glue Job script. And above df.apply() may a good way to set the value to the column.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer if it was able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not using pandas, I can't use df.apply(). I have to use withColumn() like snippet below:

```
sparkSeriesSanitize = f.udf(sanitize_status, StringType())
elementDataF = elementDataF.withColumn("new_column", sparkSeriesSanitize(elementDataF.element)))
```